# Spring Inject/AutoWire a Groovy Class that is created at runtime

Tags: java, spring, groovy

I have a Spring Controlled Grovoy Script Executor class that executes a Groovy Script.

Something like below

```
    final ClassLoader parent = getClass().getClassLoader();
    final GroovyClassLoader loader;

    loader = AccessController.doPrivileged(new PrivilegedAction<GroovyClassLoader>() {
        @Override
        public GroovyClassLoader run() {
            return new GroovyClassLoader(parent);
        }
    });


    this.groovyClass = loader.parseClass(" def returnSomthing() { return SpringControlledBean.action('Hello World') } ");
    final GroovyObject groovyObject = (GroovyObject) this.groovyClass.newInstance();
    final Object[] args = { };
    final Object result = groovyObject.invokeMethod("returnSomthing", args);
```

Is it possible to inject the *SpringControlledBean* in to the script ? via maybe a autowire, or get Spring to create the class understanding that the class will need to be recreated as the script will change?

Autowire is possible if the class was part of the classpath and built with the java, but this script content is past at runtime, so not static for spring to know about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an instance of `AutowireCapableBeanFactory`, that you can get by declaring your class as a `BeanFactoryAware`, and then you can call method `autowireBean(existingBean)`.

For example:

```
class MyBeanCreator implements BeanFactoryAware {

  private AutowireCapableBeanFactory beanFactory; //you need to add setter as well

  def foobar() {
    //your existing code....
    final GroovyObject groovyObject = (GroovyObject) this.groovyClass.newInstance();

    //Wire with Spring 
    beanFactory.autowireBean(groovyObject);

    //rest of your existing code...
  }

}
```

See also: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/AutowireCapableBeanFactory.html

Comment: This works for a Groovy class, but for a plain groovy script (with def functions), it doesn't work. Autowired need to be a field or Method/Constructor. Maybe there a away of amending the groovy class file generated.

Comment: yes, there is nothing to wire for plain script. you can wrap it with all required stuff before wiring/executing for example