# Injecting Spring Beans to Groovy Script

Tags: spring, groovy

I've seen many examples about Groovy objects as Spring beans but not vice versa. I'm using Groovy in a Java EE application like this:

```
GroovyCodeSource groovyCodeSource = new GroovyCodeSource(urlResource);
Class groovyClass = loader.parseClass(groovyCodeSource, false);
return (GroovyObject) groovyClass.newInstance();
```

In this way, classes written in Groovy with `@Configurable` annotation are being injected with Spring beans. It's OK for now.

How can I get the same by using `GroovyScriptEngine`? I don't want to define a class and I want it to work like a plain script. Is Spring/Groovy capable of that?

I've seen a post about this but I'm not sure whether it answers my question or not:

[HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14957980/spring-inject-autowire-a-groovy-class-that-is-created-at-runtime#comment21079319_14972681)

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean that you'd like to add properties to the script, and inject those? Would you provide getter and setter? This does not make much sense to me. What makes sense, is adding the mainContext to the bindings of the script, or adding selected beans to the bindings.

These beans - or the context - would then be accessible directly in the script, as if it was injected.

```
def ctx = grailsApplication.mainContext
def binding = new Binding([:])
Map variables = [
        'aService',
        'anotherService'
].inject([config:grailsApplication.config, mainContext:ctx]) { m, beanName ->
    def bean = ctx.getBean(beanName)
    m[beanName] = bean
    m
}
binding.variables << variables

def compiler = new CompilerConfiguration()
compiler.setScriptBaseClass(baseScriptClassName)
def shell = new GroovyShell(new GroovyClassLoader(), binding, compiler)
script=shell.parse(scriptStr)
script.binding=binding


script.init()
script.run()
```